# Is Java Web Start broken?

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, jnlp

I have several applets converted to webstart apps which, after running fine for years, recently quit working. They fail with a "FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource".

Looking around online I have been unable to find a single .jnlp file that works.

I'm currently using Windows 7, Java 9.04

For an example of the error, try running the [dynamictree_applet.jnlp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/examples/applet_ComponentArch_DynamicTreeDemo/src/dynamictree_applet.jnlp) from Oracle's [Deploying an Applet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html) Tutorial page.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: My jnlp apps are mysteriously working again -- don't ask me why -- so never mind I guess. Leave a note if you know what was going on the last few days...